# Escaping strings for gsub

Tags: lua, gsub

I read a file:

```
local logfile = io.open("log.txt", "r")
data = logfile:read("*a")
print(data)
```

output:

```
...
"(\.)\n(\w)", r"\1 \2"
"\n[^\t]", "", x, re.S
...
```

Yes, logfile looks awful as it's full of various commands

How can I call `gsub` and remove i.e. `"(\.)\n(\w)", r"\1 \2"` line from data variable?

Below snippet, does not work:

```
s='"(\.)\n(\w)", r"\1 \2"'
data=data:gsub(s, '')
```

I guess some escaping needs to be done. Any easy solution?

---

**Update**:

```
local data = [["(\.)\n(\w)", r"\1 \2"
"\n[^\t]", "", x, re.S]]

local s = [["(\.)\n(\w)", r"\1 \2"]]

local function esc(x)
   return (x:gsub('%%', '%%%%')
            :gsub('^%^', '%%^')
            :gsub('%$$', '%%$')
            :gsub('%(', '%%(')
            :gsub('%)', '%%)')
            :gsub('%.', '%%.')
            :gsub('%[', '%%[')
            :gsub('%]', '%%]')
            :gsub('%*', '%%*')
            :gsub('%+', '%%+')
            :gsub('%-', '%%-')
            :gsub('%?', '%%?'))
end

print(data:gsub(esc(s), ''))
```

This seems to works fine, only that I need to escape, escape character `%`, as it wont work if `%` is in matched string. I tried `:gsub('%%', '%%%%')` or `:gsub('\%', '\%\%')` but it doesn't work.

---

**Update 2**:

OK, `%` can be escaped this way if set first in above "table" which I just corrected

:terrible experience:

**Update 3**:

*Escaping of `^` and `$`*

As stated in Lua manual ([5.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1), [5.2](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1), [5.3](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1))

> A caret `^` at the beginning of a pattern anchors the match at the beginning of the subject string. A `$` at the end of a pattern anchors the match at the end of the subject string. At other positions, `^` and `$` have no special meaning and represent themselves.

So a better idea would be to escape `^` and `$` only when they are found (respectively) and the beginning or the end of the string.

*Lua 5.1 - 5.2+ incompatibilities*

> `string.gsub` now raises an error if the replacement string contains a `%` followed by a character other than the permitted `%` or digit.

There is no need to double every `%` in the replacement string. See [lua-users](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaFiveTwo).

Comment: To escape "pattern" characters in Lua string in a variable, use this function: https://github.com/lua-nucleo/lua-nucleo/blob/v0.1.0/lua-nucleo/string.lua#L245-L267

Answer (score 21):

According to [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html):

`` The character `%´ works as an escape for those magic characters. So, '%.' matches a dot; '%%' matches the character `%´ itself. You can use the escape `%´ not only for the magic characters, but also for all other non-alphanumeric characters. When in doubt, play safe and put an escape. ``

Doesn't this mean that you can simply put `%` in front of every non alphanumeric character and be fine. This would also be future proof (in the case that new special characters are introduced). Like this:

```
function escape_pattern(text)
    return text:gsub("([^%w])", "%%%1")
end
```

It worked for me on Lua 5.3.2 (only rudimentary testing was performed). Not sure if it will work with older versions.

Comment: Instead of `[^%w]` it is easier to use `%W"`, which is basically the same. According manual: _"An upper case version of any of those classes represents the complement of the class"_

Answer (score 7):

Why not:

```
local quotepattern = '(['..("%^$().[]*+-?"):gsub("(.)", "%%%1")..'])'
string.quote = function(str)
    return str:gsub(quotepattern, "%%%1")
end
```

to escape and then `gsub` it away?

Answer (score 3):

try

```
line = '"(\.)\n(\w)", r"\1 \2"'
rx =  '\"%(%\.%)%\n%(%\w%)\", r\"%\1 %\2\"'
print(string.gsub(line, rx, ""))
```

escape special characters with %, and quotes with \

Comment: As `s` in my script is variable, and not hard-coded string, can you provide more info as which characters needs to be escaped for `gsub`? I made functions to transform string to byte sequence and back again, as a workaround, but then found out that I can't tell Lua to convert byte to string in anything but ASCII.

Comment: see the reference manual on patterns to determine what needs to be escaped http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1. in the case above, parens and backslashes are special characters in that they're used in the pattern matching scheme to determine special constructs (captures or to indicate special characters).

Answer (score 2):

Try `s=[["(\.)\n(\w)", r"\1 \2"]]`.

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck for some reason

Comment: This would work if file is read line by line and line compared to s, but not with `gsub`

Answer (score 1):

Use `stringx.replace()` from Penlight Lua Libraries instead.

Reference: https://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/libraries/pl.stringx.html#replace

Implementation (v1.12.0): https://github.com/lunarmodules/Penlight/blob/1.12.0/lua/pl/stringx.lua#L288

Based on their implementation:

```
function escape(s)
    return (s:gsub('[%-%.%+%[%]%(%)%$%^%%%?%*]','%%%1'))
end

function replace(s,old,new,n)
    return (gsub(s,escape(old),new:gsub('%%','%%%%'),n))
end
```