# Lua -- match strings including non-letter classes

Tags: string, lua, match

I'm trying to find exact matches of strings in Lua including, special characters. I want the example below to return that it is an exact match, but because of the `-` character it returns `nil`

`index = string.find("test-string", "test-string")`
returns nil

`index = string.find("test-string", "test-")`
returns 1

`index = string.find("test-string", "test")`
also returns 1

How can I get it to do full matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also ask for a plain substring match that ignores magic characters:

```
string.find("test-string", "test-string",1,true)
```

Comment: In my situation, this is the best answer. This is because the second "test-string" is actually user inputted so I need to check for an exact match.

Answer (score 5):

`-` is a pattern operator in a Lua string pattern, so when you say `test-string`, you're telling `find()` to match the string `test` as few times as possible. So what happens is it looks at `test-string`, sees `test` in there, and since `-` isn't an actual minus sign in this case, it's really looking for `teststring`.

Do as Mike has said and escape it with the `%` character.

I found [this](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial) helpful for better understanding patterns.

Comment: This was helpful, do you have any advice for finding these special characters in a string and replacing them with themselves and a `%` prefacing them? maybe using `string.gsub`?

Answer (score 2):

you need to escape special characters in the pattern with the `%` character.

so in this case you are looking for

```
local index = string.find('test-string', 'test%-string')
```

Comment: Great, so a follow up question -- where `test%-string` will be is actually going to be input from a user. So now I have to search for special characters such as `-` or `.` and place a % infront of each one. Do you know how I would go about doing that?

Comment: yes, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790688/escaping-strings-for-gsub) has a good example of how to escape input strings.

Comment: Thank you I'll select final answer for you!